# Вычисление Vector2 для AddForce() с учётом поворота по оси Z

Tags: c#, unity3d, вектор

Всем привет! Делаю проект в 2Д возникла сложность с вычислением вектора для метода AddForce(). Необходимо толкнуть объект с учётом его угла по оси Z. Решил с помощью костыля разместил перед точкой спавна еще один объект. Хотелось бы реализовать то же самое но более элегантно

```
public override void Move(Transform spawnPosition, Transform target)
{
    // Двигаем объект на точку спавна
    rb.transform.position = spawnPosition.position;
    rb.transform.rotation = spawnPosition.rotation;

    // Вычисляем вектор направления с помощью координат вспомогательного объекта
    Vector2 forceDirection = target.transform.position - spawnPosition.position;

    rb.AddForce(forceDirection, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так чтобы получить вектор координат, не нужен объект, это же просто 2 числа. Вопрос: "вперед" - это куда, как это отличается например от " назад"?

Comment: В моём случае это положительные значения по оси Х в локальных координатах. пробовал через Vector2.right, но не получилось.

Comment: Ну `new Vector2(1, 0)` вроде положительный. Попробуйте его просто напрямую в AddForce использовать.

Comment: @aepot изменил вопрос, и добавил картинку для наглядности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Vector2 forceDirection = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.up)
```

Так ты переведешь вектор (0, 1) из локальной системы координат в глобальную (в твоем случае как раз с нужным поворотом)

Comment: Спасибо то что нужно.